# Identify primary key in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, orm

Is there any way to identify the Primary key of an entity class in my JSP page. 
For Eg: If i call a function, i need to get back the @ID parameter declared in the entity class as return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very obvious how to do this. Assuming that all your entities will look like about the following:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

  private Long id;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(...)
  public Long getId() {
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    return id;
  }

}
```

you simply write `myEntity.getId()`.

Comment: but what if we have two fields set as @Id. then how can we identify which one is the primary key in the database ?

Comment: if 2 fields are set as `@Id`, then that 2 fields together forms the primary key afaik.

Comment: If you have a composed primary key, it depends on your strategy. Multiple @Id fields will cause exceptions. A simple form of composed ID is to use an `@EmbeddedId`. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite for an example in Hibernate 5 (also valid for hibernate 4). You get the ID in the same way: `myEntity.getEmbeddedId().getWhatever()`